# Is sending a cookie with a sessionid in every HTTP response considered a bad practice?

Tags: cookies, session-management, django

My Django application sets a `set-cookie: sessionid=xxxx; expires=Thu, 16-May-2019 18:54:59` (and some more, like max-age and path) on every response. The sessionid remains the same until the session ends. I can see the purpose of this: By setting the expire time, the time when the browser should drop the cookie can well be controlled, and set to an up to date value every request made.

Two things:

- A security expert told me, that this is at least "un-normal" behaviour, normally the sessionid cookie should be set on login only, and the server would then just invalidate the cookie if it's no longer valid
- My current configuration is `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE=True` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE), so, the expire is no more a thing, right, and in theory, setting the cookie after login only would be ok.

But, I from my side see no downside on setting the header on every response - I mean, I pass the sessionid on to the server with every request already, and it just kinda returns it (with up to date expires)...?

**UPDATE**

This is called "Sliding Window", as some of the answers have stated. And, most say it is not bad practice, but some of you dont agree at all - topic remains oppiniated.

Comment: To clarify, when you say it sets `set-cookie: sessionid=xxxx` on every response, does it give the `sessionid` the same value, or a new value every time? Some of the answers seem confused about this.

Comment: yes, just saw this and clarified, thanks! (it's remaining the same!)

Comment: it doesnt seem very clear if this is bad practice - half of answers tell yes, other half no...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django default is secure.

Changing the way Django sessions work in a way that is not through a supported setting would be less secure, because if you replace django sessions with your own sessions module (or monkeypatch some code in Django's session module) you rely on yourself for security instead of relying on the Django community for security.

Your site should also be HTTPS-only and if so set [SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-secure) to True.

Comment: thanks, yes, I applied all the remaining "upgrading security" settings! I just wonderd if I configured something the wrong way round...

Comment: I'm not a big fan of this answer because it's very specific to Django and does not answer the general case of the question, but indeed, if the Django devs took care to make this secure, it's probably best to just leave the default instead of rolling your own.

Answer (score 2):

To best answer your questions, I need to cover a few areas to explain how **COOKIES** work and why it is useful to leverage them.  This is based on my past experience with leveraging cookies in my past solutions.

## COOKIES IN GENERAL

The purpose of **COOKIES** are to define something which gets sent **in every request from the client to the server** and **back to the client in case those COOKIES get updated or told to clean up.**

The purpose of persistent **COOKIES** is if the user closes the browser and re-opens it again, then the persistent **COOKIES** will be re-sent up in the next re-connection (stored only for that user's workstation login) so-as to resume without sending the user back to a **LOGIN** or **SSO AUTH** again because they have not yet expired.

This is beneficial because if you have a solution where you could have multiple **TABS** open to the **SAME WEB SITE** to multi-task work, you can re-use the **COOKIES** to resume and scale easily.  Also, if the browser crashes, it can restart and resume easily to put the user back where they were last at as a convenience.

## SESSION COOKIES

In my experience, it is common to have a **SESSION COOKIE** containing the **SESSION ID** and then the **DOMAIN** or **SUB-DOMAIN** to control security access by the page loaded by this **DOMAIN** or **SUB-DOMAIN**.

You shouldn't have to define an **EXPIRATION** on a **SESSION COOKIE** because the **EXPIRATION** should be set to **'Session'** as the Server will know if it is expired or not.

Depending on your Web Server used, look for these type of SESSION EXPIRATION settings.

## AUTH COOKIES

To guard against replay attacks, I've also seen **AUTH COOKIES** which have a **SLIDING EXPIRATION**.  This means the **EXPIRATION** will **SLIDE** to a forward date/time of your **EXPIRATION WINDOW** for **IDLE EXPIRATION**.

IIS uses both **SESSION COOKIES** and **AUTH COOKIES**, but for whatever reason, IIS will not start **SLIDING EXPIRATION** on the **AUTH COOKIE** until it reaches **50%** of the time to the initial **EXPIRATION** of the **SESSION COOKIE**.  It then **SLIDES EXPIRATION** every request until the **SERVER** expires the **SESSION**.

## SLIDING EXPIRATION FOR SESSION

Although good practice is to **SLIDE EXPIRATION** of the **SESSION** on the **SERVER** with every **REQUEST** received as you are actively communicating with the **SERVER** to support certain solutions where a system may need to remain up **24x7**.

## LOGOUT CAPABILITY

If concerned about persistent **COOKIES**, you can give the user a control to **LOGOUT** of the Web Site.  When a **LOGOUT** occurs, the Web Server can request the Web Client to clear out all of it's related **COOKIES**.

Also, you can configure the OS to clear out the **COOKIES** on actual **LOGOUT** from their **WORKSTATION**.

Depending on your solution, you can adjust these rules to where if no user interaction on the **CLIENT**, the client can request to **LOGOUT** and cleanup based on your rules.

## REPLAY ATTACK PROTECTION WITH AUTH COOKIES

As for protecting against a replay attack of all network traffic, the server should be validating the **AUTH COOKIE** **VALUE** to only use it once per **REQUEST** and changed to a new **AUTH COOKIE** **VALUE** which is has listed as available in a **CATALOG** maintained on the **SERVER**.  (Multiple TABS can get tricky here so you have to decide how to deal with allowing multiple uses of the same **AUTH COOKIE**.)

**COOKIES** are protected (unlike the earlier years pre-2000) so-as to keep other web sites from jumping their gates and accessing your site's **COOKIES** illegally to hijack your **LOGIN SESSION**.

## PERSISTENT COOKIES ARE SAFE TO USE

It is perfectly safe to use **PERSISTENT COOKIES** because you define the window of usefulness with an expiration date which should be around 15-20 minutes at most.  **SESSIONS** on the Server should also only last at most 20 minutes before they **SLIDE** forward another 20 minutes after every request is received.

## ANSWERING YOUR QUESTION

The **SESSION COOKIE** should have an **EXPIRATION** set to **"Session"**.  Configure the Web Server to manage the **SESSION** **EXPIRATION** for you and expire it after an **IDLE TIME PERIOD** passes.

The **SESSION COOKIE** should automatically be **SENT** by your **CLIENT BROWSER** without writing any special code.

Your **WEB SERVER** should manage the **SESSION EXPIRATION** for you, but the **RESPONSE** should always write the **SESSION COOKIE** and other **COOKIES** back to the **CLIENT** in every **REQUEST** to update them if they **CHANGE**.

## RECENT ALTERNATIVE

With recent adoption of **JWT Tokens**, a **JWT Token** can serve both as **SESSION** and **AUTH TOKEN** as it contains an **EXPIRATION** and is **SIGNED** to protect against tampering.  It also could be used to add some level of **ZERO TRUST** capability to your solution.

However, you have to **write the code on the client and server** to support it.  Where-as the **COOKIE** use is automatic and common with most modern **WEB SERVERS**.

Comment: thank you, for your (long) answer. I know how cookies work ;-) so, you say it's not bad practice. but I dont see a explantation why it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

What purpose does updating the cookie on every request serve?  The server must validate the cookie on every request anyway.

You say you see no downside in doing this.  Ok, but what's the upside of doing it?  I don't see one.  Why do extra work for no gain?  It just increases complexity.

Comment: I do no extra work, it's Django that does it. I wonder if it could be disabled ;-) at least in `SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE` mode.

Comment: The upside is an up to date expires value. I know...that could and should be done server side as well.

Comment: Do you see a downside, security wise? If an attacker can read my traffic, he can get the sessionid from the request anyway.

Comment: While I agree, this does not answer the question. "Is climbing a tree considered bad practice?" is not answered by "why would you climb a tree, what's the upside?"

Answer (score 0):

> My Django application sets a `set-cookie: sessionid=xxxx` on every
>   response. I can see the purpose of this: By setting the expire time,
>   the time when the browser should drop the cookie can well be
>   controlled, and set to an up to date value every request made.

No, you are wrong. You are not setting the expire time for the cookie by doing that.

> A security expert told me, that this is at least "un-normal"
>   behaviour, normally the session id cookie should be set on login only,
>   and the server would then just invalidate the cookie if it's no longer
>   valid

Yes. You only have to give a session cookie to the user once and destroy it at logout - not change it with every request. Doing that serves no purpose and is an overhead to the server.

> But, I from my side see no downside on setting the header on every
>   response - I mean, I pass it on to the server with every request
>   already...?

I don't get it. So you keep changing his session token and then migrate all the data that corresponds to one session to another? Isn't that just stupid?

Comment: sorry, clarified my question, it does set expire. also, the sessionid remains the same, until the session ends. it's just that in the response, there is always the set-cookie header...

Comment: But why would you set-cookie again and again?Give it one expiry.And does the session id change with every request?

Comment: As I clarified, the sessionid remains the same, across all requests. If setting one expiry, it will just end then. This just seems not how Django works...it will extend the sessionid's expiry, with every request...as far as I understand.

Comment: "If setting one expiry, it will just end then" thats not how it is supposed to work.You set an expiry in the future and the session remains until then.When the user logs out you set the session expiry in the past or delete the session cookie.That how it was taught to me

Comment: but what if the user is active, and not expecting the session to end just when the initial expiry was set? should not the session be extended? that I would destroy the session cookie when I logout is normal, and also how Django does it.

Comment: thats why you set the expiry in months.Session can stay as long as he doesn't log out.There is no security issue there

Comment: It's called "sliding window." If you want a cookie that expires 10 minutes after your last interaction, the only way to do it is to set a new cookie with each interaction. This is not at all uncommon.

Comment: thx @JohnWu. Looks like there are quite some different oppinions out there! Some say you should do it server side only, some, as you, say it's legit and common (and not bad practice, security wise, as I understand...)